# Redirect Output with Iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

Is possible on Debian to change the port of packets that are going to a specific port, using iptables?

**Example:**

I want packets going in the outbound direction to a.b.c.d for port 1723 to be redirected to the address a.b.c.d on port 10000.  Is this possible?

Comment: Please use standard terminology like source and destination.  Am I correct in assuming you want iptables to change the destination port on outbound packets to a specific host from 1723 to 10000 for both TCP and UDP?

Comment: @jw013 You're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for proto in tcp udp; do
  sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d a.b.c.d -p "$proto" --dport 1723 -j DNAT --to-destination a.b.c.d:10000
done
```

Comment: This only works if ip forwarding is activated: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`